# How to update using for loop on a groupbox?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I was about to make an update after saving data using sql-server.
I am using the same code in the insert method.

This is my code

```vb
For i = 1 To Me.Controls.OfType(Of GroupBox).Count
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dlog", dtp_date_make.Value)
Dim gb As GroupBox = CType(Me.Controls("Groupbox" & i), GroupBox)
For Each ctrl As Control In gb.Controls
                   If TypeOf ctrl Is Label Then
                       Dim lvl As Label = ctrl
                       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ptbi", lvl.Text)
                   End If
                   If TypeOf ctrl Is CheckBox Then
                       Dim chck As CheckBox = ctrl
                       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@io", chck.Checked)
                   End If

                   If TypeOf ctrl Is ComboBox Then
                       Dim com As ComboBox = ctrl
                       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rem", com.Text)
                   End If
                   If TypeOf ctrl Is NumericUpDown Then
                       Dim nud As NumericUpDown = ctrl
                       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@wono", nud.Value)
                   End If
               Next
               conn.Open()
               cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
               cmd.Parameters.Clear()
               conn.Close()
```

My groupbox is from 1 to 23. After updating
When I look at my database, Groupbox23 which is id 23 the last id evade from id 1 to id 22.

Comment: While debugging, what value returns `Me.Controls.OfType(Of GroupBox).Count`? Have you tried with a `For Each` loop instead? Are your GroupBoxes all direct children of the Form? Is it possible that one is inside another container?

Comment: While debugging, what value returns Me.Controls.OfType(Of GroupBox).Count? 
Ans. the last groupbox which is groupbox 23.

Comment: That method doesn't return a GroupBox, it returns an Integer. As the other points, it's a debugging issue.

Comment: any idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: when debugging it only read from groupbox1 to groubox23.. after the update all inside of groupbox23 updates from id 1 to id 23 in database my idea is groupbox1 updates id1 and so on. i guess i had to get id table first but i dont know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe write it out like this

```
    For Each GrpBox As GroupBox In Controls.OfType(Of GroupBox)
        For Each Ctrl As Control In GrpBox.Controls
            Select Case Ctrl.GetType
                Case GetType(Label)
                    'do stuff with label'
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ptbi", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DirectCast(Ctrl, Label).Text

                Case GetType(CheckBox)
                    'do stuff with CheckBox'
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@io", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = DirectCast(Ctrl, CheckBox).Checked
            End Select
        Next
    Next
```

Comment: Ok... whats the exception?

Comment: i found out whats the problem. the problem is when i use for loop for groupbox1 for example inside of the groupbox 1 has label,checkbox,combobox and numericupdown. when i track it using messagebox for query when i stop to groupbox4 i saw my sql databas, from id1 to id23 groupbox4 update it all this crazy its supposed to update it like groupbox1 is for id1 and groupbox2 is for id2 sorry for my english but did u get my point?

Comment: I dont know what you are trying to tell me. update your code in the OP please